# При очередной загрузке Ubuntu появилось меню GNU GRUB

Tags: ubuntu, grub, gnu

При очередной загрузке Ubuntu 16.04 появилось меню GNU GRUB

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В нем выбираю первый пункт, этот выбор приводит к:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как мне вернуть работоспособоность системы?

Comment: initranfs - было у меня это - все инструкции в сети не помогли - вставил диск именно с той ubuntu которая стаяла - и всё - типа восстановление

Comment: Загрузиться с какого-нибудь rescuecd и проверить разделы с помощью `fsck` как и указано на скринах.

Comment: Спасибо за советы!

Comment: Восстановление с использованием LiveUSB не помогло. В итоге совсем повалил систему, даже GRUB перестал запускаться... Видимо что-то делаю не верно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Почему появился этот экран?

Во время работы OS были обнаружены ошибки на диске (ошибки файловой системы). И система "просит", чтобы вы провели сканирование диска 'fsck' вручную. Это нормальная ситуация, OS пытается избежать потери данных.

#### Как решить?

- можно подключить диск к другому серверу и протеcтировать
- можно использовать [Ubuntu LiveCD](http://help.ubuntu.ru/manual/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81_livecd)
- использовать [RecoveryMode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) или [Single user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub)

> Важно! Причиной возникающих ошибок может быть неисправность диска и в первую очередь нужно убедиться, что диск исправен.

Если это ваша основная система - выполните резервное копирование диска или ключевых данных.

p.s. Подобные ситуации сильно напрягают поначалу, но помогают лучше разобраться в логике работы и понять алгоритм восстановления системы.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение причин произошедшего.